# Twitter API 1.1 How would I show who tweeted it and the profile picture using php

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to search tweets with Tesla and have it display the tweet, profile pic, time of tweet, and tweet id. I can only get it to show the tweet, time, and id. What do I need to do to get it to who tweeted it and the profile picture
The code I have is below.

```
<?php
require_once('TwitterAPIExchange.php');

$settings = array(
'oauth_access_token' => "",
'oauth_access_token_secret' => "",
'consumer_key' => "",
'consumer_secret' => ""
 );
 $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json";
$requestMethod = "GET";
$getfield = '?q=Tesla&result_type=recent&count=10';
$twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
$string = json_decode($twitter->setGetfield($getfield)
->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
->performRequest(),$assoc = TRUE);
foreach($string['statuses'] as $tweets) {
echo $tweets['text'] . '<br>';
echo $tweets['created_at'] . '<br>';
echo $tweets['id_str'] . '<br>';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I switched over to twitteroauth and it made everything much easier. The solution that I found if anyone is needed is below.

```
<?php
include "twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php";


$oauth_access_token = "xx";
$oauth_access_token_secret = "xx";
$consumer_key = "xx";
$consumer_secret = "xx";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$oauth_access_token,$oauth_access_token_secret);

$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=Tesla&result_type=recent&count=10');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Twitter API SEARCH</title>
 </head>
<body>
<?php foreach ($tweets->statuses as $key => $tweet) { ?>
   Tweeted BY: <img src="<?=$tweet->user->profile_image_url;?>" /><?=$tweet->user->screen_name; ?> <br>
  Tweet :<?=$tweet->text; ?><br>
  ID : <?=$tweet->user->id_str;?> /><br>
  Tweeted on : <?=$tweet->created_at;?> <br> <BR>
<?php } ?>


</body>
</html>
```